# How to get the numbers after the decimal place for an if statement in php

Tags: php, decimal

I am just trying to figure out how I can get the actual digits of a figure that has been calculated within php and formatted to have 2 decimal places.

so say its calculated it to be 45.76  I am trying to figure out how I can get the 76 from it for an if statement.  Basically I want it to look and just say that if it's 00 then remove them, if not, show them.

Thanks

Comment: Add some code with what you've tried, you might be closer than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
function showDecimals($v){
   $n = abs($v);
   $whole = floor($n);       
   $fraction = $n - $whole; 
   return  $fraction > 0
}
```

And...

```
if (showDecimals(10.15)){
  //Show
}else{
  //Remove?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a whole number if there is no decimal place, and 2 decimals of precision if not?

## Method 1

```
function formatNumber($n) {
    $n = round($n*100)/100;

    return ''+$n;
}
```

This simply rounds it to 2 decimals of precision.  Zero truncation is automatic.

### Usage

```
echo formatNumber(0);       //0
echo formatNumber(0.5);     //0.5
echo formatNumber(0.894);   //0.89
echo formatNumber(0.896);   //0.9
echo formatNumber(1.896);   //1.9
```

## Method 2

Or if you 1.9 to display as 1.90, I suppose this would work:

```
function formatNumber($n) {
    if ($n == 0)
        return ''+$n;

    $str = ''.round($n*100)/100;

    $dotpos = strrpos('.', $str);

    if (strlen(substr($str, $dotpos+1)) === 2)
        $str .= '0';

    return $str;
}
```

### Usage:

```
echo formatNumber(0);       //0
echo formatNumber(0.5);     //0.50
echo formatNumber(0.894);   //0.89
echo formatNumber(0.896);   //0.90
echo formatNumber(1.896);   //1.90
```

**Edit:**  Accidentally posted broken version of method 2, should be fixed now.